# Deploy GWT Web Application to Jetty 7 in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jetty

I'm attempting to configure a standard Jetty (7.4) runtime in Eclipse that I can deploy my GWT webapp to (we're going to be using Jetty in the field).

After I install the proper Eclipse plugin and set up the server runtime, when I get to the dialog where it actually asks which webapps to deploy, I can see my application in the list on the left, but when I select it, I get the message "Jetty version 7.0 only supports J2EE 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, and Java EE 5 Web modules."

But, when I build my application's WAR, I'm able to deploy it on Jetty manually.

Is there something special I need to configure within the project to make Eclipse think it can be deployed to Jetty?

By the way, I am able to deploy the application into a Tomcat 7.0 server configuration without a problem.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem? I am having the same issue with no luck.

Comment: Not yet, although I haven't had a lot of time to work on it as I've been pulled off the project for a little while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to make this work.

One of my project facets was set as "Dynamic Web Module" version 3.0.  Apparently Jetty doesn't support this.

I had to manually go into the project config and change this to version 2.5, and Eclipse now lets me add this to Jetty.

Note that this could cause problems for some web apps, but mine seems to be okay.